# like operater not working on hive,what to do?

Tags: hive, hiveql

select * from cancel where deduction_percentage like '%100% cancellation charge%';

SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:27 Wrong arguments ''%100% cancellation charge%'': No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFLike with (array, string). Possible choices: *FUNC*(string, string)

Comment: The exception says that `deduction_percentage` is an Array. `like` works with strings. Concatenate array using `concat_ws`or use array_contains(Array, value) function. Or compare array element using`[]`

Answer (score 1):

Your deduction_percentage seems like array datatype. The query you written will work for string datatype fields only.

```
select * from cancel where concat_ws(',',deduction_percentage) like '%100% cancellation charge%';
```

Comment: this is what i got...

hive> select * from cancel where concat_ws(',',deduction_percentage) like '%100% cancellation charge%';
OK
Time taken: 0.095 seconds
hive>